# TIMESTAMPDIFF from particular timezone

Tags: mysql, sql

I can get the timezone offset from the database time to UTC (0) using the following:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, UTC_TIMESTAMP(), NOW());
```

How would I get the number of hours offset from `UTC` to a particular timezone, for example, "America/New_York" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have timezone support set up in MySQL (see the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html)), you can do this:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, 
                     UTC_TIMESTAMP(), 
                     CONVERT_TZ(UTC_TIMESTAMP(), 'UTC', 'Australia/Adelaide')
                     ) / 60
```

Output

```
10.5
```

Note that you should take the difference in minutes and divide by 60 as some timezones have half hour differences.